# how can I solve this: Too many pixels in sample; must be <= 262144. Got 700494 (Earth Engine)

Tags: python, google-earth-engine

I'm trying to convert an ee.Image to a Numpy array. Somehow small areas are computed correctly, yet big amounts of pixels present an error related to the max amount of pixels using the function sample.Rectangle.

Here's the code:

```py
import numpy as np
import ee

naipCollection = (
    ee.ImageCollection("USDA/NAIP/DOQQ")
    .filterBounds(a_file)
    .filterDate("2017-01-01", "2020-12-15")
)
naip = naipCollection.mosaic()
naipNDVI = naip.normalizedDifference(["R", "N"]).rename("NDVI")
demClip = naipNDVI.clip(a_file)
vegetacion = demClip.gt(0).lt(0.4).selfMask()
naip_b = naipNDVI.reproject("EPSG:32613")
array_or = naip_b.sampleRectangle(a_file, defaultValue=0)
arr_or_or = array_or.get("NDVI")
np_arr = np.array(arr_or_or.getInfo())
nonzero_or = np.count_nonzero(np_arr)
```

Comment: format your question properly please